# How Do I Use Mysql's IF EXIST for Validation?

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to get the syntax right.  I'm looking to check a table for a value before allowing another record to be inserted.

Something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE id = 1)
THEN
INSERT INTO other_table (room_id) VALUES (1)
END IF
```

I just want to make sure a particular record exists before it's allowed to be entered in another table... To go even further, I'd actually like to make sure a couple things exist...

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE id = 1) AND (SELECT * FROM guests WHERE guest_id = 10)
THEN
INSERT INTO other_table (room_id,guest_id) VALUES (1,10)
END IF
```

I'm not up on transactions yet, or stored procedures, so if I need to learn all of that first, I'm going to be sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` :

```
INSERT INTO other_table (room_id) 
SELECT 1 FROM rooms WHERE id  =1 GROUP BY id
```

(`GROUP BY` just to make sure the subquery returns no more than 1 row; if `rooms.id` is unique, you don't need it.

For multiple tables:

```
INSERT INTO other_table (room_id,guest_id) 
SELECT 1, 
10
FROM rooms WHERE id = 1 and exists (SELECT 1 FROM guests WHERE guest_id = 10) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: interesting... so if nothing is returned it will just ignore the insert?  You think this will work for multiple conditions too?

Comment: @aiex07 I'm not having any success with this syntax in instances where I need to compare more than one record :/

Comment: @Jascha: added example for 2 tables.